# Как выполнить метод класса программы из модуля в С++ программе

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

Есть основная программа написанная на C++/QT. Написал плагин для этой программы, подключаю плагин всё работает как надо. Могу из программы через интерфейсный класс, который обязательно наследуется плагином, вызвать небходимый метод. Но в самой программе реализован функционал в разных классах, который я хотел бы вызывать внутри плагина, что-то вроде API. И никак не могу этого сделать. Пытался использовать map с указателями на инстансы этих классов с передачей по интерфейсу в плагин, но в конечном счёте всё заканчивается подобной ошибкой: plugins/User/libUser.so: undefined symbol: ZN10SystemUserC1Ei. Даже узнал что такое Делегаты, но и от них толку внутри плагина никакого.
То есть получается что плагин не знает ничего про классы внутри программы, даже если я через #include подключаю файл с описанием класса, это не даёт никаких результатов.
Может кто подскажет в каком направлении копать?

Comment: Что в вашем понимании плагин, уточните? Библиотека, либо это просто доп класс или отдельная прога?

Comment: Имею в виду библиотеку .dll или .so

Comment: Библиотека не может зависеть от основной программы, вам правильно внизу пишут - пересмотрите архитектуру.

Comment: Неужели нет таких программ на С++ которые могут расширяться с помощью .so независимыми разработчиками и при этом чтобы можно было в .so использовать общий API приложения?
Хорошо может не "библиотеки", а есть какой-то другой путь, которого я не знаю?

Comment: Вы просто можете сделать проект (cmake) включающий в себя подпроекты (add_subdirectory а не add_library), и они будут ссылаться друг на друга без всяких проблем.Либа - это независимая вещь, чей функционал используется в проекте/проектах

Answer (score 2):

Лучше все организовать через сигнал-слоты.
Каждый плагин должен иметь возможность отправить сигнал с параметрами (const QString &key, const QVariant &value) к примеру.
Главная программа получает все эти сигналы и анализируя key выполняет какие-то действия. При необходимости в value передавать параметры для запуска функции.
Допустим, если key == "shutdown", то необходимо закрыть основную программу.

В интерфейсе плагина добавляем сигнал:

```
signals:
        void sendMessage(const QString &_sKeyName, const QVariant &_vValue);
```

В основной программе, после загрузки плагина, подключаем его к своему слоту:

```
connect(plugin, &VisualPlugin::sendMessage, this, &ManagePlugins::onReceiveMessageFromPlugin, Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

и реализация слота:

```
void ManagePlugins::onReceiveMessageFromPlugin(const QString &_sKeyName, const QVariant &_vValue)
{
if(_sKeyName == PluginCommands::appExit())
    {
        close();
    } else if(_sKeyName == PluginCommands::setStudentId())
    {
        selectRowByStudentId(_vValue.toInt());
        showWnd();
    }
}
```

Для удобства, текстовые key команды я поместил в отдельный h файл в namespace PluginCommands, который доступен и основной программе и плагинах.

Так же в интерфейсе плагина можно определить виртуальный слот. и когда в основную программу приходит сообщение от любого плагина - ретранслировать сообщения в все плагины. Таким образом может работать обмен сообщений между плагинами.

Comment: Неплохой вариант, надо попробовать сделать нечто подобное.

Comment: А сможет ли плагин связаться со слотом из самой программы?

Comment: Да, у меня такой механизм работает.

Comment: @Александр , интерфейс по идее не должен наследоваться от `QObject`, т.к. класс самого плагина обязан наследоваться от `QObject` (двойное наследование от `QObject` в Qt не поддерживается), а значит не может и отсылать сигналы. Каким образом в этом случае Вы выстраиваете подключение плагина?

Comment: а почему нельзя интерфейс наследовать от QObject? В самом плагине я наследуюсь только от VisualPlugin, но указываю макрос Q_OBJECT. Если нет желанию наследовать интерфейс от QObject, можно просто добавить виртуальную функцию.

Comment: @Александр , ну просто чтобы сигналы из плагина можно было подключить к основной программе, нужно чтобы сам класс интерфейса наследовался от `QObject`. По идеологии Qt (и не только) интерфейс - это класс, содержащий исключительно чисто виртуальные (`pure virtual`) методы и ничего более, в то время как наследуя его от `QObject`, мы тем самым нарушаем эту схему.

Comment: @Александр , даже если макрос `Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE` и примет класс интерфейса, унаследованный от `QObject` (не проверял), то налицо ломка схемы подключения плагина (описана в документации), и которую можно поставить в один ряд с такими подходами, как например передача списка указателей на функции из главной части в плагин для обратного вызова.

Comment: Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE  примет. Я привел свой пример, он работает и удовлетворяет своим функционалом, Если унаследовать сам плагин от QObject, то основная программа не будет знать о существование слотов и сигналов плагина, соответственно подключиться не получится.

Comment: @Александр , да, не получится, о том и речь. И в этом основная идея, подсказывающая, почему не стоит интерфейс наследовать от `QObject`. В сложном и предусматриващем расширение проекте, разумеется.

Comment: Не знаю на сколько авторитетный источник, но вот тут описан метод о котором я и говорю: https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Qt/%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E

Comment: @Александр , Вы не поняли. Речь не о том, можно или нельзя. Речь о том, стоит ли. Приведу пример: зачем автору произвольного кода сознательно ограничивать для себя возможности вызова методов класса из вне, располагая некоторые из них в секциях `private` и `protected`? Пусть бы все в `public` были... Та же самая ситуация.

Comment: @alexis031182, фреймворк предлагает мощную систему сигналов-слотов, она вполне адекватно работает в плагинах, так почему бы её не использовать? Лезем в исходники qt, вижу интерфейс QSqlDriverPlugin, унаследованный от QObject, и QMYSQLDriverPlugin унаследованный от QSqlDriverPlugin и содержащий макрос Q_OBJECT. Если уж разработчики используют такой подход, то что уж говорить.

Comment: @Александр , считаю, что это не правильно. В этом случае плагин легко превращается из ведомого в ведущего: может отсылать сигналы, когда захочет, а не когда его попросит об этом основной код программы. Нарушение концепции ведущий-ведомый - потенциальное приглашение потратить лишнее время на длительную отладку.

Comment: Видимо, у меня с Вами разное представления предназначения плагинов.

Comment: @Александр , нет, нужно просто помнить, что плагин - это не программа, принимающая решения, а всего лишь библиотека, расширяющая функционал основной части кода, и которую последний использует в своих целях, но не наоборот.

Comment: Кстати, несмотря на наследование `QMYSQLDriverPlugin` от `QSqlDriverPlugin` и соответственно `QObject`, никакие сигналы не используются. Сим фактом разрабы Qt частично реабилитированы :))

Comment: ну хорошо, скачиваем исходники qt creator, открываю первый попавшийся плагин и вижу что он наследуется от IPlugin из src\libs\extensionsystem, который наследуется от QObject, имеет макрос Q_OBJECT и сигнал asynchronousShutdownFinished().

Comment: @Александр , поторопился я, значит, с похвалой :))

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо пересмотреть архитектуру программы. Плагины - это всегда опциональный функционал, который не может и не должен использовать код основной части программы. Даже если этот код является вспомогательным.

Если очень нужно, чтобы плагин использовал некий набор классов из основной части программы, то оформите и их в отдельный плагин и подключайте, как и из основного плагина, так и из основной программы.

Comment: Вроде верное замечание, но как тогда организовать API приложения и при этом чтобы была возможность расширения приложения. Я только с помощью .so вижу выход. Организовать API через отдельную библиотеку вполне возможно, но тогда увеличивается сложность библиотеки т.к. в каждой придётся делать подключение API. Да и это ещё пол беды. Я делаю приложение которое выполняет роль бакенда. Соединения обрабатываю через websocket. Я бы хотел реализовать базовый функционал в приложении, и с помощью библиотек (.so) дальше расширять его.

Comment: В этом случае API не должен подключаться напрямую к главной части (серверу), а должен подключаться прозрачно через плагины, которые реализуют свой кастомный функционал. Я бы сделал один некий базовый плагин для API, а другими дополнительными плагинами расширял бы его функции в случае их подключения. Тогда получится один единственный универсальный интерфейс общения сервера с плагинами, по сути с API, которое будет задействовано в одном из подключенных в текущий момент плагинов. Что касаемо сложности, то разумеется её уровень будет расти, раз уж выбран путь расширяемой функциональности.